# Can we have an inflection point without $f'(x)$ being zero or undefined?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let's say $f'(x)=x(x-2)\implies f''(1)=0$. Also, $f'(x)$ is not changing sign around $x=1$.

Here, can we say $x=1$ is a point of inflection for $f(x)$?

Comment: The sign of $\,f'\,$ does not matter here. The second derivative $\,f''\,$ changes sign at $\,x=1\,$, so the function changes convexity, so that's an inflection point.

Comment: @dxiv, thanks. If $f''$ is zero or undefined at one point and on the left side of that point, $f''$ is positive and on right side, it is zero, would we say that point is an inflection point?

Comment: Depends on what your definition is of an inflection point for functions that are not continuously differentiable.

Comment: To answer the title question: yes, for example $f(x)=x^3+x$ at $0.$